# What happened to EC-ATQ?

Tags: incidents

EC-ATQ was a Douglas DC-7C.
It was damaged beyond repair on 2.10.1970 in Madrid.
Does anyone have more information?

Was a piano dropped on top of it and nobody was willing to take the blame?